# Gun standoff game I devised for myself (basic probability problem)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I devised a probability problem for myself to help me better understand conditional probability (because I am evidently missing something very crucial).

The rules:

- $k$ players are arranged in a circle, each with a gun trained on the player in front of them.
- Each player only has one bullet in their gun. Only one player shoots at a time, in the order they are arranged in the circle.
- Each player has a probability $p_n$ of their bullet hitting their target (n $\in{[1, k]}$).
- Each player can only shoot at the player in front of them (aka the one they have their gun trained on).
- If a player dies, the player next in the circle fires.
- The game ends when every bullet is fired (so max $k$ gunshots).

I manually worked out the scenarios for $k = 2, 3, 4, 5$. See below for the picture. (The number of possible outcomes for each $k$ follows a Fibonacci sequence, which is cool, but not unexpected.) What I'm having trouble with is working out the probabilities--if the $p_n$ for each player is distinct, how do I work out the probability of Player $n$ surviving?

[Cases for k = 2, 3, 4, and 5 players.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1onaA.jpg)

My attempt for $k = 2$: 
$p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$ = probability of Player 1 surviving. 
Is this the correct calculation? I don't think so.

There is also the arrangement (not shown in the picture above) where the Player 2 fires first, then Player 1 fires. In this second case, probability of Player 1 surviving (by my faulty logic) is: 
$(1-p_2)(p_1) + (1-p_2)(1-p_1)$ 
And so would the final probability, considering all cases for $k = 2$, of Player 1 surviving be: $p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2) + (1-p_2)(p_1) + (1-p_2)(1-p_1)$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Additionally, I have no idea why you're talking about the possibility that player 2 fires first.  This doesn't even make any sense unless you want to introduce a probability distribution on who fires first.  Without that, the most sensible thing you can do is just _define_ player 1 to be the first shooter.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right, I was definitely being confusing. I have now edited the post so that hopefully things are more clear now.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Because each player's $p_n$ is distinct, The chances of survival for Player 1 would be different if Player 1 shot first vs. if Player 2 shot first, no? Would you mind clarifying what you mean when you say I end up computing the "expected number of survivors"? (And thank you for your comments, they've been helpful in trying to understand this!)

Comment: Even if all probabilities $p_n$ are equal, each player's probability of surviving depends on who shoots first. And if you know that Player 2 will shoot first, you can simply renumber everyone (and their probabilities) so player 2 is now called player 1, the number that was called $p_2$ is now called $p_1$, etc., apply the solution you found when player 1 shot first, and then renumber everyone and their probabilities back the way they were originally. (to be continued ...)

Comment: ... So the idea that Player 2 can shoot first is really interesting only if there is a **probability** that Player 1 shoots first, a **probability** that player 2 shoots first, and similarly for other players if there are any. This is what is still missing from the problem statement. It's easy enough to assume an arbitrary probability distribution over who shoots first, but only if that's what you want.

Comment: By the way, if $p_1=0.9$ and $p_2=0.1$, then $$p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2) + (1-p_2)(p_1) + (1-p_2)(1-p_1) = 1.89,$$ which is absurd as a value for the probability that player 1 survives. Again, what is missing in your calculation is any concept of a random variable that says which player shoots first.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, I think I see what you mean by your first two comments! In that case, is my calculation that Player 1 survives for $k = 2$: $p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$ correct?

Comment: You have to give a better response to the question of who shoots first before you can ask that question. Shall we assume Player 1 is always first, or is there some other scheme such as a probability distribution?

Comment: If we assume Player 1 is always first, then yes, the probability that Player 1 survives is $p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2) = 1 - (1 - p_1)p_2.$

Comment: @DavidK Thank you so much! What I'm struggling now with though, is the following: So for the case k = 2, the probability that Player 1  (the black circle) survives is $p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$.  The probability that Player 2 (the white circle) survives is $(1-p_1)(p_2) + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$. Let's say that Player 1 has a 50% chance of hitting Player 2 AND that Player 2 has a 50% chance of hitting Player 1. Thus, Player 1 has a 75% chance of surviving, and Player 2 has a 50% chance of surviving. [to be continued]

Comment: However, there are 3 possible outcomes; Player 1 survives in 2 of them, and Player 2 survives in 2 of them. So, "intuitively" I suppose, you would assume that Player 1 and Player 2 should have EQUAL chances of surviving. Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: Do not assume that outcomes are equally likely unless you have a good reason to. In this case, the only source of probability is the chance of hitting, which is $1/2$ in both cases. So you first divide the possibilities into two equally likely outcomes depending on the first shot. Then you divide **one** of those outcomes a second time. This produces two outcomes of probability $1/4$ while leaving the remaining possibility with probability $1/2.$

Comment: Note that in the two-player game where player $1$ shoots first, you have correctly stated the probability that player $2$ survives, but you can simplify it: $(1-p_1)(p_2) + (1-p_1)(1-p_2) = 1 - p_1,$ that is, player $2$ survives exactly when player $1$ misses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just consider the case where Player $1$ shoots first.
But let the number of players be $k$ for arbitrary $k \geq 2.$

To help keep the notation concise, let $s_n$ be the probability that player $n$ survives.

Player $1$ certainly shoots at player $2,$ because player $1$ always survives long enough to shoot. Player $2$ survives if and only if player $1$ misses.
Therefore $$s_2 = 1 - p_1.$$

But every other player shoots if only if they survive, and therefore player $n$
(for $n \geq 3$) survives if player $n-1$ dies (probability $1 - s_{n-1}$)
or if player $n-1$ survives and misses (probability $s_{n-1}\left(1 - p_{n-1}\right)$).
These are mutually exclusive outcomes, so we can add their probabilities:

$$
s_n = \left(1 - s_{n-1}\right) + s_{n-1}\left(1 - p_{n-1}\right) = 1 - s_{n-1}p_{n-1}.
\tag1
$$

This agrees with the observation that player $n$ dies if and only if player $n-1$ survives and hits, so we can subtract that probability from $1$ to find the probability that player $n$ survives.

The calculation for player $1$ is similar except that the player behind player $1$ is player $k$, so

$$
s_1 = \left(1 - s_k\right) + s_k\left(1 - p_k\right) = 1 - s_k p_k.
$$

This provides a $k$-step procedure to calculate all the probabilities.
In the first step you compute $s_2.$ Next, you compute $s_3,$ then $s_4,$ and so forth until all the survival probabilities up to and including $s_k$ are known,
and then you compute $s_1.$

You can use just one equation if you make the following change in notation:
the probability that player $1$ survives is called $s_{k+1},$
while $s_1 = 1$ is not a survival probability.
Then all survival probabilities can be computed by Equation $(1).$

If the probabilities $p_n$ follow some kind of formula then you might be able to come up with a more direct way of computing each $s_n,$ like the way we can state a formula for the $n$th Fibonacci number.
For example, if $p_n = \frac12$ for every $n,$ then for $n \geq 2$ (using the notation where $s_1=1$ and player $1$'s probability of survival is $s_{k+1}$)

$$
s_n = \frac23 \left(1 - \left(-\frac12\right)^n \right).
$$

More generally, if $p_n = p,$ the same $p$ for every $p_n,$ then for $n \geq 2,$
$$
s_n = \frac1{1+p} \left(1 - \left(-p\right)^n \right).
$$

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you so much for all your help. Your answers and comments have been crucial in teaching me the errors in my logic. (Hopefully) one final question: do you mind clarifying how you arrived at the last two equations (where you assume $p_n = p$, where $p$ is constant? Thank you again!

Comment: These sequences are called recursive sequences because you can compute the $n$th term from the value of the preceding term. The Fibonacci sequence is also recursive, using the two previous terms. There are some general techniques for finding formulas for recursive sequences. But to be honest, in this case I was lazy and just asked Wolfram Alpha for the answer. ... But it's fairly easy to guess the term in front of the parentheses, because it's the number which, if it were the value of $s_{n-1}$, the value of $s_n$ would be the same. (Just solve for $s$ in $s=1-sp.$)

Comment: If you try computing the sequence for a couple of different examples, it will be clear that it converges to a probability, and $1/(1+p)$ is what it converges to.